# How to handle `MongoException`?

Tags: mongodb, scala, alpakka

I don't know, how to detect and handle `MongoException` in case of `MongoDB disconnect`

```
  val pingCmd: Publisher[bson.Document] = mongoCollFactory.db.runCommand(BsonDocument.parse("""{"ping": 1}"""))
```

detect `MongoException` which does not connect to the database and then returns `MongoException`
Ex. `when pingCmd is success -> HealthCheck.OK
then pingCmd failed -> HealthCheck.Failed`

Answer (score 0):

If you are  writing a function that implies and I/O, and can fail,  os highly recomended to encapsulate it in a Either or an Option.

***1. Either approach***

```
try{
  val pingCmd:Publisher[bson.Document] = 
   mongoCollFactory.db.runCommand(BsonDocument.parse("""{"ping": 1}"""))
  Rigth(pingCmd)
}catch{
  case e:Exception => Left(e)
}
```

In another point of the execution, you can handle the exception or log a warning. You can find more info about either in ScalaDoc (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/Either.html)

***2. Option approach***

Using the monad option, you can  have a value in case the operation succeeds, or none value if it fails. This solution provide less information about the error, becouse None does not encapsulate information about the exception, while Either does it.

```
try{
  val pingCmd:Publisher[bson.Document] = 
   mongoCollFactory.db.runCommand(BsonDocument.parse("""{"ping": 1}"""))
  Rigth(pingCmd)
}.toOption
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it is not working. when disconnecting the database, it must be print `Exception`. but it prints `success`

Comment: ```   val eitherPing = try{
    val pingCmd:Publisher[bson.Document] = mongoCollFactory.db.runCommand(BsonDocument.parse("""{"ping": 1}"""))
    Right(pingCmd)
  }catch{
    case e:Exception => Left(e)
  }
  eitherPing match {
    case Right(_) => println(Console.GREEN + s"Success -> " + Console.RESET)
    case Left(value) => println(Console.RED + s"Failed: $value" + Console.RESET)
  } ```